# Ray: Memory management when calling tune.run() multiple times within python script

Tags: python, memory-management, reinforcement-learning, ray

I have a python script that trains a reinforcement learning model using, among others, the libraries `ray` and `rllib`. The script uses check-pointing to update an `rllib.PPO` model iteratively. In every iteration, I redefine the configuration and call `tune.run()`, where I provide the checkpoint of the previous iteration to the restore variable. For each call to `tune.run()`, I only request one worker. Before entering the loop I initialize ray and request a large number of resources.

The problem is that memory increases quickly, until `ray` complains that the workers do not have enough memory and comes to a halt. Using htop, I can see that my python script goes from 6% to 80% within the first 10 iterations. I am wondering how I can release the resources at the end of each iteration, so that memory usage does not increase with running time.

Here's a (pseudo)code of my script:

#### initialize ray

`ray.init(object_store_memory=50000000000, memory=50000000000)`

#### training loop

```
for iteration in range(niterations):
  new_config = ...
  prev_checkpoint = ...
  tune.run('PPO', restore= prev_checkpoint, config=new_config)
```

As you can see, I am not currently doing anything to release resources. Also, calling `ray.init()` within the loop gives an error indicating that multiple calls of it are not possible. Finally, requesting more memory at the beginning is not possible and would not solve the problem, as I would like to perform thousands of iterations while keeping memory usage constant.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I solved the issue. It was not necessary to release any resources after calling `tune.run()`, the memory issue was due to building a tensorflow graph within each iteration. I realised that, quite annoyingly, the only way to release resources allocated by tensoflow is to terminate the python interpreter (closing the tensorflow session does not release them). I therefore wrote a script for building and training the graph, which I call using `os.system()`. Quite hacky, but I am not aware of any other solutions.

Comment: Maybe use a `ray.remote(max_calls=1)` function to run a TensorFlow session while staying in PythonLand but resolving your memory issues?

Comment: Any news on this? I'd like a better solution eventually.